# Migrating project to new experimental gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I try to migrate my Android project to new experimental gradle plugin. I followed instructions at [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) page. I made changes in required files, but I have an error when I trying to Sync project with gradle files.

> Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

`build.gradle` in my `app` folder is very similar to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    maven {
        url = getBaseRepository()
        credentials {
            username = NEXUS_USERNAME
            password = NEXUS_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

def int CACHE_LIMIT = CACHE_CHANGING_MODULES_FOR_SECONDS.toInteger()

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor CACHE_LIMIT, 'seconds'
}

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "<myRealAppIdIsHere>"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 14
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18

            multiDexEnabled = true
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            /*buildConfigField.with {
                create() {
                    type = "boolean"
                    name = "DEBUG_BUILD"
                    value = rootProject.ext.debugBuild
                }
            }*/
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += 'proguard-rules.pro'
            /*buildConfigField.with {
                create() {
                    type = "boolean"
                    name = "DEBUG_BUILD"
                    value = rootProject.ext.releaseBuild
                }
            }*/
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    // my dependencies are here...
}
```

Does anybody know where the problem is? I do not know why error message contains problem about ProductFlavor, because my project has no flavors...

**UPDATE**

I tried to clean my project - clean was not successful, but the error message during clean is more specific:

> Error:(10, 1) A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Exception thrown while executing model rule: com.android.build.gradle.model.BaseComponentModelPlugin$Rules#createVariantData(org.gradle.model.ModelMap, org.gradle.model.ModelMap, com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager) > afterEach()
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
>   Cannot set readonly property: minSdkVersion for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl

But still I do not know how can I fix it.

Comment: This can happen in a multi-module project.  Do you have more than one module in your project?

Comment: we have same issue. our project contains one module. how can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

In case this is not the real file in your project, make sure you have:

```
minSdkVersion.apiLevel
targetSdkVersion.apiLevel
```

instead of:

```
minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion
```

I had the same issue and this fixed it.

Comment: How is this associated with **createVariantData** error?